# How to use theme.json override feature in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes, wordpress-gutenberg

Here in the [WordPress documentation about new block theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/block-theme-overview/#global-styles-presets) They have said about overriding theme.json. I did something like that, but I don't know how o use it? Currently I have a theme.json file in the theme root (and it is working like a charm). I have this:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "settings": {
        "appearanceTools": true,
        "color": {
            "custom": false,
            "defaultPalette": false,
            "palette": [
                ...
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I have two separate files (dark.json and light.json inside styles directory). Both dark.json and light.json are something like this:

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "settings": {
        "appearanceTools": true,
        "color": {
            "custom": false,
            "defaultPalette": false,
            "palette": [
                ...
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But what I get is the original palette in theme.json when using the Gutenberg editor. How can I choose two customized palettes?

Answer (score 0):

I've found it! You can go to Dashboard -> Appearance -> theme Customize.
Then in the top right corner of this page, You can see a black and white icon titled "styles". It does show the list of style variants.

BTW, when I was searching I found this article about [new block theme style variations](https://richtabor.com/wordpress-style-variations/). Hope this helps someone else.